# Removing User ability to manage own alerts

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I've been trying to figure out how to get my alert emails that go out to either not display any way for the user to manage their own alerts or remove this functionality from individual users.  I have about 30 low tech users and I don't want them to be able to make changes to their notifications.  I have not been able to find a way to do this.  Is anyone aware of one?  I've also played with setting a workflow as an alternative but the workflow still displays a manage my alerts option.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exactly secure it but you could start with modifying the alert template for generic list (and others as you see fit). This will allow you to remove the "Modify my alerts" link from the emails.

1. Navigate to your HIVE\Template\XML\alerttemplates.xml
2. Make a copy as custom_alerttemplates.xml in the same folder
3. Open it and search for "MySubsUrl" or "$Resources:Alerts_link_modify" (there will be one of these sections for each template in this file)
4. Change the markup to remove the two  tags for this section
5. `stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -filename 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\XML\custom_alerttemplates.xml' -url http://yoursitecollectionroot/`
6. Restart Timer Service
7. Delete & Re-Add alert
8. Wait 5 min or run 'Immediate Alerts' timer job

Comment: I am apparently unable to access that source as I'm running on a Sharepoint Online site.  Any ideas?